# Saving a PIL image gives different pixel values

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I want to create a 2-by-2 image, with all pixels being red, and I want to do this by converting a NumPy array into a PIL image.

Here is my attempt:

```
pixels = np.array([[[255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0]], [[255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0]]])
image = Image.fromarray(pixels.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
image.save('image.png')
```

However, when I view this saved image, only the top-left pixel in the image is red, and all the other pixels are black. In fact, no matter what the contents of the `pixels` array, the image is always red in the top-left, and black everywhere else.

But f I print out the pixel data:

```
print image.getpixel((0, 0))
print image.getpixel((0, 1))
print image.getpixel((1, 0))
print image.getpixel((1, 1))
```

I get:

```
(255, 0, 0)
(255, 0, 0)
(255, 0, 0)
(255, 0, 0)
```

So why is the saved image not red everywhere?

Comment: What do you get if you load the saved image?

Comment: I am guessing the top left thing is the entire image itself.

Comment: Maybe there's problem with your viewer instead (this size of image is a bit of a corner case, when you think about it)? When I try it here, for example IrfanView when zoomed shows an odd gradient, but opening it in Paint.Net, it's all correct.

Comment: If I load the saved image and print out the pixels, it gives me four lots of (255, 0, 0). However, I have tried loading it in 3 different viewers (GIMP, Pinta, Image Viewer, all in Ubuntu), and they all display it in the same way, with only to top-left pixel red...

Comment: I just tried this and it worked fine.  (Mac OS X, Python 3.5.2, numpy 1.11.2.   `PIL.PILLOW_VERSION` is 3.3.0.)